# Update UI lists modules/themes that are already updated

Tags: 7, updating

I have a D7 (7.69) site. On both dev and production, I can update a module (using the web UI - */admin/modules/update*), apparently successfully, yet afterwards, that module *stays* listed as requiring an update with *Installed Version* and *Recommended Version* exactly the same.

e.g.

> Adminimal - Responsive Administration Theme (Theme)
>   Installed version 7.x-1.26
>   Recommended version 7.x-1.26

(I've seen it with themes, such as the one above, and modules such as *Views*).

I've tried:

- clearing the cache
- downloading a clean latest version to a new directory, and comparing the md5hashes of all files between the two (as well as simpler checks like the module *.info* file.)
- wiping the module/theme directory and replacing with a freshly extracted .tar.gz
- checking if any database updates are pending (they're not)

Is there anything else that could be causing it to get stuck?

I've looked at the *system* table - specifically the `system.info` field - but nothing looks "wrong".

Comment: `wiping the module/theme directory` when you do this, does the message disappear? just wondering if perhaps you have duplicate modules/themes under the /core folder or somewhere else in your code base.

Comment: @NoSssweat - good suggestion, but yes (e.g. deleting /sites/all/modules/views clears it from the Update list, and it reappears as soon as it's downloaded and extracted again, same if I also delete the row from the system table).

Comment: @NoSssweat just FYI, caused by another module changing the status in a hook, as per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by the [Update Status Advanced Settings (update_advanced)](https://www.drupal.org/project/update_advanced) module.

I didn't know this module was installed or what it was, so here's how I traced it back:

*modules/update/update.compare.inc* is where the core update module checks versions of each module and theme, beginning with *update_calculate_project_data()* - this creates a $project array that contains current/recommended versions, plus a numeric 'status' key.

'status' is a constant, set in *modules/update/update.module*, with values including:

```
define('UPDATE_CURRENT', 5); // project is up to date
define('UPDATE_NOT_CHECKED', -1); // Project's status cannot be checked.
```

I used Xdebug on *update_calculate_project_data()*, specifically tracking the modules that were stuck on the update screen.

They all had a status of `UPDATE_CURRENT` initially (as expected/desired), but that changed to `UPDATE_NOT_CHECKED` after the call to the hook in line 363:

```
drupal_alter('update_status', $projects);
```

Searching the code base, found this hook is implemented in *sites/all/modules/update_advanced/update_advanced.module:50* by *update_advanced_update_status_alter()*

If you've got this module, the settings page is */admin/reports/updates/settings*; you can instruct it to not *warn* you about specific modules.

The side effect is that by changing the status to anything other than `UPDATE_CURRENT`, a module/theme will always be listed in the Update UI (modules/update/update.manager.inc:94), including if the module *is* "current" really.

Comment: Worth filing a bug report.